# POST value associated with submit input type using django.test.client.Client

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test for a Django view that involves submitting a form (written by someone else) that looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/oauth2/token" class="authenticate">
 <input type="hidden" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code">
 <input type="hidden" name="code" value="73c2c13e4957331f4183bdfafd1f1c">
 <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/9e22123649f8cb8de8e85e70c64969/">
 <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="9e22123649f8cb8de8e85e70c64969">
 <input type="submit" value="123456">
</form>
```

When using the Django test client, I'm not sure how to submit the value that corresponds to the "submit" input type. In particular, what should go in place of the `???` below:

```
c = django.test.client.Client()
response = c.post('/oauth2/token', {"grant_type": "authorization_code",
                             "code": code,
                             "redirect_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/9e22123649f8cb8de8e85e70c64969/",
                             "client_id": "9e22123649f8cb8de8e85e70c64969",
                             ???: "123456"})
```

Comment: Step 1.  Add a print statement to the view function you're trying to test.  Step 2.  Look at the results from a real POST.  Step 3.  Compare the real POST with your unit test POST.

Answer (score 3):

The submit input type only passes a value to the request if it's named. So all you need to do is something like:

```
...
<input type="submit" name="_submit" value="123456">
...
```

It will then be available in the request as '_submit' (or whatever you want to call it).